# Edas submission warning

Tags: pdftex

Just uploaded a manuscript to EDAS that I used Latex to generate the PDF, but got three warnings:

1. The paper has 1 column, but should have 2.

The paper has two columns! Couldn't find this error on Google yet.

2. The gutter between columns is 0.014 inches wide (on page 9), but should be at least 0.12 inches.
3. One or more fonts are not embedded.

Does anybody know how to solve these warnings?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Probably something in your code is not as they expect it. I'd try looking at your `.tex` file and any console output and log files.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in your page 9, you have a figure which expands to both columns. This causes EDAS to shoot a warning. I'm not sure of a certain solution (It's more like a bug in EDAS checking system), but trying to play with your figure and increase the space between your probable subfigures might help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the third point about fonts not embedded, you can use the Adobe printer to do it. It comes with paid Acrobat software, however, you can use it for free for 7 days trial.

In the first answer in this thread, you can find detailed instructions on how to embed all the fonts using Adobe printer: 
[Embed all the fonts during compiling with pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149012/embed-all-the-fonts-during-compiling-with-pdflatex)

Good Luck!