# Create a PDF file with embedded fonts with pdflatex to be edited in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: pdftex, embedding, acrobat

I'm trying to generate a PDF file with pdflatex, that can be edited later (during review time) with Acrobat Pro.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Then, the PDF is created using pdflatex. And the goal is to later go to Acrobat Pro and be able to edit the text after selecting this tool:

Acrobat 8 and below:
Tools-> Advanced Editing -> Touchup Text Tool

Acrobat 9 and newer:
Tools -> Content -> Edit Document Text

Then, you select a word and type something to try to replace it with new content, and the following warning occours:

> "All or part of the selection has no available system font. You cannot
>   add or delete text using the currently selected font."

If I check the File->Properties->Fonts in Acrobat Pro, it says that the font is Embedded Subset.

I tried to use the technique described in [Turning off font subsetting in pdftex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24002/turning-off-font-subsetting-in-pdftex) and that allows me to embed all the fonts. But still, the same problem arises when I try to edit the text in Acrobat Pro.

The output of the PDF file with pdffonts is the following:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
CCFBMP+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
```

and the output from pdffonts after embedding the fonts as in [Turning off font subsetting in pdftex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24002/turning-off-font-subsetting-in-pdftex) is:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
LMRoman10-Regular                    Type 1            Custom           yes no  no       4  0
```

Any idea on what is still missing to allow editing in Acrobat Pro?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you installed Latin Modern Roman as a system wide font? If not, Acrobat will not be able to find it. (There may be other issues, but there will at least be this one.) If not, either install Latin Modern for your OS or (if this is an option in Acrobat) add the TeX installation's copies for use in the application or switch to a font which is available systemwide. You might find it easier to work with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX which use OS fonts.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that moving to XeLaTeX was a solution! :D

Comment: @cfr -- if the file is to be shared, won't using latin modern still be susceptible to problems on systems other than the originator's where that font isn't resident?  seems to me that this will be reliable only if the font is one of the common minimum complement of fonts supplied for "all" common systems.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed. But it isn't clear to me that is required. In any case, there really is no such 'common minimum complement of fonts'. Given that editing will be in Acrobat Pro, the best option in that case would be to use a font included with Acrobat rather than hoping that the OS provides a particular font.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve the issue that I just found is to change the compiler to XeLaTeX, and then specify a font that Acrobat can use, for example by adding this before \begin{document}:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

Then, the PDF generated can be edited in Acrobat Pro without issue.

I will just end up using this file for review, and generate the final version to print without the above code and with the LaTeX compiler.

Not ideal.. but works for now.

Let me know if you have any idea of how to improve it! Thanks!