# (Possible?) How to embed a specific font (not from LaTeX package) to the output PDF?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, compiling, embedding

Say I have a specific font myfont.ttf on my own computer.

I have a PDF file created by another software, which uses this font.

Then I use beamer (PDFlatex) to include this PDF file the final output file.

Is it possible during the compilation from beamer, to include this font to the final PDF file?

Comment: In a pdflatex produced pdf the font subsets used in the document are automatically embedded.  Included pdfs are just inlined as-is.  Also I'd be very careful with embedding whole fonts, as most licences forbid this.

Comment: http://www.myfontfree.com/bradley-hand-itc-myfontfreecom126f36994.htm Does this mean they are free? Just to double check again, I dont really understand what does it mean by "the font subsets used in the document are automatically embedded"? Because when I bring the document to another computer,which the font is not installed, the PDF files would not display correctly where that particular font was used. And when I check the PDF file, I can clearly see that "bradley hand itc" was NOT embedded.

Comment: This font is not free.  The location you posted is offering the font for free illegally.  To purchase a license go to [fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-bradley-hand).

Comment: Bradley Hand ITC comes with Microsoft Windows.  Adobe Acrobat for Windows has the “feature” that it cannot correctly display documents with embeded TrueType fonts which are already installed in Windows.

Comment: These posts might also help you: [How to embed fonts at compile time with pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-to-embed-fonts-at-compile-time-with-pdflatex), [Turning off font subsetting in pdftex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24002/turning-off-font-subsetting-in-pdftex), [Installing TTF fonts in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex)

Comment: @HenriMenke Good grief. Why on Earth do they do that?

Comment: Note that the first of the links includes the kind of strategies you want i.e. the cases for inclusion of external images. You either need to pre-process the images or process them on-the-fly as part of the compilation process.