# Problem with the embedding of tex-gyre and truetype fonts

Tags: fonts, pdftex, embedding, truetype

First of all, I should say that this is my first question here, so please be patient if I lack initial detail and thanks in advance for any help.

I am compiling a document with pdflatex from a TeXLive 2013 version. I need to embed all fonts, or otherwise the uploaded document is returned as non-compliant.

I have configured

```
pdftexDownloadBase14 true
```

in udpmap.cfg, and I have tried to follow [these steps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24002/turning-off-font-subsetting-in-pdftex/24005#24005) to create a full font embedding map, with no success. The output of pdffonts is

```
name                   type       encoding         emb sub uni object ID
---------------------- ---------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Helvetica              Type 1     Standard         no  no  no      86  0
Helvetica              Type 1     Standard         no  no  no      89  0
Times New Roman,Bold   TrueType   WinAnsi          no  no  no     271  0
Times New Roman,Bold   TrueType   WinAnsi          no  no  no     277  0
Helvetica              Type 1     Standard         no  no  no     296  0
Helvetica              Type 1     Standard         no  no  no     299  0
```

and the font embedding window in `evince` outputs the following:

[image: Font embedding errors as per Evince]

Is there any way I can make sure that all fonts are embedded?

Comment: Did you check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-to-embed-fonts-at-compile-time-with-pdflatex If you did not, go ahead and check it to see if that solves your problem. The search box is your friend :)

Comment: Welcome! Otherwise, can you provide a complete but minimal document which reproduces the issue? We need code we can compile to try to reproduce the problem. Why are you using TeX Live 2013? (This shouldn't matter - just seems old.) Which `updmap.cfg` did you edit? Did you run `updmap-sys` afterwards? Have you ever run `updmap` or `getnonfreefonts` (i.e. without the `-sys`)?

Comment: @AFeldman sure, I did. It worked in the past, so I am not really sure why it does not for this specific document.

Comment: @cfr, I am trying your steps, will let you know if it works asap.

Comment: @cfr, as a follow-up, unfortunately those steps do not help. Working on an MWE, will be back soon.

Comment: I asked questions to try to figure out the problem. I didn't offer a solution. But you haven't answered the questions.