# Type 3 - LaTeX to PDF

Tags: pdftex

I'm a tech support in our school but I'm not a programmer nor a Linux user and I receive Math students with problems to convert their LaTeX documents into a PDF file with the Type 3 fonts embeded but not SUBSETED. therefore, their deposit (PDF file) is rejected because the font are not properly integrated.
So, for now I recommand that they use  only Type 1, OpenType or TrueType Fonts with Times New Roman, Calibri or Symbols glyphs.

So I have 3 questions:

1. Will it be possible in LaTeX3 to have a full conversion possibility of PS Level Type 3 fonts into PDF ?
2. If not, would it be possible that type 3 fonts are not used by default?
3. Is there something else I can tell them to help ?

Thank you
Wassif

Comment: By default the main TeX distributions include Type 1 fonts and Type 3 fonts are not normally used. So if your students are submitting files with Type 3 fonts then they are using an unusual TeX set up. For fully embedding fonts, perhaps this will help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24002/turning-off-font-subsetting-in-pdftex

Comment: @down-voters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.