# Using pdflatex, is it possible to control low-level PDF constructs?

Tags: pdftex

I'm trying to control what the PDF looks like (as in a text or hexadecimal editor) to make it easier to parse and modify with external tools. For instance, if I want to change a string within the document, I need to make sure that the included font has the glyphs needed for the new string.

Is it possible to instruct pdflatex to include a whole font even if the current text doesn't use it all?

Is it possible to make sure that font definitions appear at the beginning of the file?

Is it possible to write verbatim `x 0 obj <<...>>` object from within the source `.tex` file so that it appears in the PDF output?

Comment: Yes, you can use low level commands like `\pdfcatalog` and `\pdfobj` in [pdftex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf)

Comment: It would have to be `\special`.

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question in one question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24002/turning-off-font-subsetting-in-pdftex on the font aspect